# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; works but browser back button doesn't?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The issue has something to do with one of my pages and browser history.  My page www.mysite.com/view.php isn't being recognized in the history of the browser even though the page loads.

If I go from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/view.php to www.mysite.com/add.php and then click the back button in the browser it takes me back to www.mysite.com.

If at www.mysite.com/add.php I use a simple:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

It spits out www.mysite.com/view.php

However when I right click on the back button to see browsing history, www.mysite.com/view.php isn't there and if I press the back button it takes me back to www.mysite.com.

The code to go from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/view.php is simply:

```
<form name="form" action="view.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</FORM>
```

The code to go from www.mysite.com/view.php to www.mysite.com/add.php is:

```
    <div class="editbtn"><a href="add.php?tripid=<?php echo $tripid; ?>" title="add activity ">add activity</a></div>
```

Any ideas what this could be?  How is it possible that a browser can miss a page?

Comment: Is there any Javascript on any of the pages that's manipulating the history?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't redirecting somewhere?  There really isn't enough information to reproduce this problem, is there?  I haven't tested it, but I suspect that if I actually made pages with the code you suggest, it will work fine.  Have you tried it?